# Java String to Date, DateFormat not working

Tags: java, date-format

I'm having a little difficulty converting a string of the below format into a date. Keeps throwing a ParseException.

String: **2015-11-14 17:29:16.543934**

I've looked around here already, notably this link: [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion), but not having any luck.

Here's what my method currently looks like:

```
private Date parseTime(String input) {
    // input format: 2015-11-14 17:29:16.543934
    try {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssSSSSSS");
        Date date = format.parse(input);
        return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not parse time. ID: " + this.id);
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT:**

On the answer I gave below (stating I missed a "." between the seconds and millis) Jon Skeet had a very good point:
"That still won't work as you expect it to. It will treat your input as having 543934 milliseconds... so it will parse as being 17:38:19."

I actually don't need this level of precision so I'm just going to cut off the milliseconds, but if anyone knows how to keep the precision of 6 decimal points I would be interested to know how.

Comment: You can keep the microsecond precision with either Java-8 (`java.time`-package) or with ThreetenBP (similar, but backport for Java-6+7) or with my library Time4J. Other libraries and the old JDK only offer millisecond precision.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the dot at the string format:

**ss.SSSSSS**

it must be:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
```

Comment: Turns out this won't work for the reason Jon Skeet gave: "That still won't work as you expect it to. It will treat your input as having 543934 milliseconds... so it will parse as being 17:38:19."

Comment: If SimpleDateFormat try to parse nanoseccond forcefully, I hear that operates like this. for example,
2015-05-08 00:00:00.123456→2015-05-08 00:02:03.000456

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a "." between the seconds and milliseconds, so the new DateFormat is as follows:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
```

Comment: Note that milliseconds can only have up to 3 digits (milli = 1000, i.e. values from 0 to 999).

Comment: That still won't work as you expect it to. It will treat your input as having 543934 milliseconds... so it will parse as being 17:38:19.

Answer (score 0):

Declare this :

```
 String tt = "2015-11-14 17:29:16.543934";
    TextView textt;
```

Then used this :

```
             try{    
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
                    Date bod = format.parse(tt);
                    SimpleDateFormat rformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    textt.setText(rformat.format(bod));
                }catch (ParseException pe){

                }
```

For Date Convert you have to used both Format.

1. **Format Before**   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
2. **Convert Format**   "dd-MM-yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

Date can not use nanosecond, can it?

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS000");
```

Answer (score 0):

'S' in SimpleDateFormat is milliseconds, and there nothing for microseconds.

In DateTimeFormatter (Java 8) 'S' means fractional part, and you can convert string without problems:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, dtf);
Instant instant = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
return Date.from(instant);
```